# How to find XPath with Google Chrome in Headless mode using Selenium?

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, xpath, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to get information from Google like mobile number for some shops/companies, and store it on a Excel sheet.

I use Chrome driver (*v_74.0.3729.6*).

It works with Chrome in **normal mode**, it finds the element with XPath, but not when I use Chrome in **headless mode**.

I tried to change the size of the window and to add some options:

```vb
.AddArgument ("--window-size=1920,1080")
.AddArgument ("--no-sandbox")
.AddArgument ("--start-maximized")
.AddArgument ("--disable-gpu")
.AddArgument ("--disable-extensions")
```

I also tried differents XPath (but if it works without headless mode, I suppose the XPath is correct):

```vb
browser.FindElementsByXPath("(//span[@class='LrzXr zdqRlf kno-fv'])[1]")
browser.FindElementsByXPath("//*[@id='uid_6']/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/span[2]")
```

I also tried to put a waiting time (to be sure the page is fully loaded):
`Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:2"))`

```
Dim browser As New ChromeDriver

With browser
    .AddArgument ("--window-size=2160,3840")
    .AddArgument ("--headless")
End With

denomination = "Fnac Lyon Bellecour"
adresse = "85 Rue de la République 69002 Lyon"
browser.Get ("https://www.google.com")
browser.FindElementByName("q").SendKeys (denomination & " " & adresse)
SendKeys "~"

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:2"))

If browser.FindElementsByXPath("(//span[@class='LrzXr zdqRlf kno-fv'])[1]").Count >= 1 Then
    telephone = browser.FindElementByXPath("(//span[@class='LrzXr zdqRlf kno-fv'])[1]").Text
    Sheets("Donnees").Cells(1, 13).Value = telephone
End If
```

It normally copies the mobile number of the shop in cell M1 but it can't find the element.

Comment: I have tried with python selenium  with chrome headless mode and it is working fine.

Comment: No need to use indexes since it is only element  `//span[@class='LrzXr zdqRlf kno-fv']`

Comment: What error message are you getting and on which line?

Comment: @KunduK : It works well on Python for me as well, but i don't know why it doesn't work with VBA on Excel on **headless mode**. It's fine in **normal mode** with VBA.

Comment: @QHarr With this code i don't have error, program just doesn't go inside the "If" loop.

Answer (score 0):

I have verified with `python selenium` with chrome headless mode and it is working fine every time i run this code.
I have used `WebdriverWait` which is explicit wait and wait for element to be clickable and then fetch the text value.

I believe you can modify this code in `VBA`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080');
driver=webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
denomination = "Fnac Lyon Bellecour"
adresse = "85 Rue de la République 69002 Lyon"
element=driver.find_element_by_name('q')
element.send_keys(denomination + ' ' + adresse)
element.submit()
print(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[@class='LrzXr zdqRlf kno-fv']"))).text)
```

### Output:

> +33 825 02 00 20

Comment: I tried to put 10sec waiting time, it's doesn't help in headless mode. (I can't wait to a specific element because it will return an error instead of let me handle the case in which no element was founded)

Comment: @Sakyo : Can resize your window and check what you are getting?

Comment: I tried some random sizes, 2160x3840 and 1080x1920. It's the same, it didn't find element.